# Binary search tree << operator overload not working

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, operator-overloading, binary-search-tree

I have 3 classes which creates a complete Binary search tree. The 3 classes are
1. DBentry(stores a name, IP address, and status),
2. TreeNode(points to its own DBentry, as well as entries to its left and right)
3. TreeDB(contains a root TreeNode and provides various functions to add, remove, update, and find DBentryobjects)

Inside DBentry I have `friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const DBentry& rhs);`
Inside TreeDB I have `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& rhs);
              friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, TreeNode* rhs);`
These overloading operators doesn't seem to work properly. Any help would be really helpful.

Class DBentry:

```
class DBentry {
private:
string name;
unsigned int IPaddress;
    bool active;

public:

DBentry();
    DBentry (string _name, unsigned int _IPaddress, bool _active);


~DBentry(); 


void setName(string _name);


void setIPaddress(unsigned int _IPaddress);


    void setActive (bool _active);


string getName() const;


unsigned int getIPaddress() const;


    bool getActive() const;

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const DBentry& rhs);
};
```

Class TreeNode:

```
class TreeNode {
private:
DBentry* entryPtr;
TreeNode* left;
TreeNode* right;

public:
TreeNode();

TreeNode(DBentry* _entryPtr);


~TreeNode();


void setLeft(TreeNode* newLeft);


void setRight(TreeNode* newRight);


TreeNode* getLeft();


TreeNode* getRight();


DBentry* getEntry() const;

bool find(string _name);


};
```

Class TreeDB has `private:
                  TreeNode* root;`

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const DBentry& rhs){
out<<rhs.name<<" : "<<rhs.IPaddress<<" : ";//<<rhs.active?    (out<<"active"):(out<<"inactive")<<endl;
if(rhs.active)
    out<<"active";
else
    out<<"inactive";
out<<endl;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, TreeNode& rhs){
if(rhs.getEntry()!=NULL){
    out << *(rhs.getLeft());
    out << *(rhs.getEntry());
    out << *(rhs.getRight());
}
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& rhs){
out << *(rhs.root);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, TreeNode& rhs)` says the function returns a reference to an `ostream`. The code does not return an `ostream` reference, so the program will go on a merry little adventure into Undefined Behaviour.

At the very least, and there may be other problems in the unposted portions of the program, OP must

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, TreeNode& rhs){
    if(rhs.getEntry()!=NULL){
        out << *(rhs.getLeft());
        out << *(rhs.getEntry());
        out << *(rhs.getRight());
    }
    return out; //<-- return the stream. Do not cross streams unless fighting Gozer.
}
```

The other `operator<<` overloads have the same flaw.

Comment: Even with return out; it gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: @FabiaBushraTamanna Is it possible for left or right to be NULL if Entry is not NULL? Printing NULL would be an easy way to crash.

Comment: Yeah left or right could be NULL. How can I fix that?